# Window.open not working inside an if condition which contains a confirmation dialogue

Tags: javascript

I am facing a strange problem with the `window.open` function.

The following code just works fine:

```
 window.open(document.getElementById("openTargetItemLink").href+ "&favItemKey=" + itemId, "contributor", "width=950,height=620,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes", false);
```

However, when the `window.open` is invoked in the following context:

```
if (confirm(myMessage))
    window.open(document.getElementById("openTargetItemLink").href+ "&favItemKey=" + itemId, "contributor", "width=950,height=620,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes", false);
```

**It doesn't work.**

Even if the `if` statement seems to be working, the window (which is expected to be open) doesn't seem to open *unless* the code above is being executed in the console included in the Developer Tool.

Comment: What browser are you testing on? Does it work on other browsers? Does it print any error message when the `window.open` call fails?

Comment: Are you sure your popup blocker isn't stopping them? Many browsers don't allow you to trigger new windows without a click event or the browser will stop them. Also, the browser usually allows one window per click event. you can try as if(true) inplace of if(confirm(myMessage)), hope this would help you :)

Comment: yes i am sure no pop up blocker is blocking them. And its not a browser issue too..

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vgfdmdt1/1/

Your `myMessage` probably have value `null` or `undefined`

Comment: nope..its defined and working fine, that is why it is going inside that if condition.

Comment: you are not using `{}` braces. check the line after the `if`. probably it is because you have many spaces behind `... myMessage))`

Answer (score 0):

I had I similar error and I don't know what caused it, but I solved it like this.

This didn't work

```
if ( something == 1 ) {
    window.open( href, "_blank" );
}
```

but this worked:

```
if ( something == 0 ) {
    return false;
}
window.open( href, "_blank" );
```